# Triggering same function on both click and keypress

Tags: jquery

I have the following function which fires when clicked but how would I also make it fire on enter without creating a new function? (if possible).

```
$("#jump_menu select option").click(function(){
    var hash = $(this).val();
    var target_offset = $(hash).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset.top}, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try binding to

```
$("#jump_menu select").change
```

...instead.

Alternatively just move it to a standalone function and bind to what you need:

```
function handler(elem) {
    var hash = $(elem).val();
    var target_offset = $(hash).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset.top}, 500);
}

$('#jump_menu select option').click(handler);
$('#jump_menu select').change(handler);
```

You may need to save and compare event timestamps though to ensure you don't call your handler twice for a single selection.

Comment: The only problem is if someone scrolls to the top and tries to reselect the previous option it doesn't fire again, and I want that to remain.

Comment: @George: in that case I would just put the code in your anonymous function in a standalone named function, and just bind it to the events you want to handle.

Comment: Thanks but now it doesn't allow the user to select the individual the options because we bound the click to the select box and not the individual options so it fires before one can select an option. =/

Comment: @George: Yeah. In testing I only _sometimes_ get that in Chrome. I think the first comment is the best idea: move the code to a function, and bind that to option/click and select/change.

Answer (score 1):

You have to globally declare your function, rather than declaring it in your .click function like so:

```
function animateBody() {
    var hash = $(this).val();
    var target_offset = $(hash).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset.top}, 500);
}
```

After that, you can bind the function to multiple event without redeclaring it twice:

```
$("#jump_menu select option").click(animateBody);
$("#jump_menu select").change(animateBody);
```

The resulting could look something like this:

```
//Other JQuery/Javascript

function animateBody() {
    var hash = $(this).val();
    var target_offset = $(hash).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset.top}, 500);
}

$("#jump_menu select option").click(animateBody);
$("#jump_menu select").change(animateBody);

//Other JQuery/Javascript
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
function runAnimate() {
    var hash = $(this).val();
    var target_offset = $(hash).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset.top}, 500);
}

$("#jump_menu select option").click(runAnimate);  

$('body').change(runAnimate);
```

Comment: sorry: $("#jump_menu select").change(runAnimate); instead last code block

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens when I press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).on('keyup , change' ,function() {
--- Do some thing ---
});
```